# appending giving strange value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I'm trying to add two lists f and l as shown below. f and l don't have the same shape so I made the shape of f similar to l

```
f = [37.37, 34.26, 33.78, 33.82, 36.33]

f.append(f)

l = [[34.4 , 39.32, 35.61, 38.12, 34.11], 
     [33.1 , 35.14, 36.76, 33.66, 34.31]]
z = f + l
```

but I'm getting this strange output :

```
[37.37, 34.26, 33.78, 33.82, 36.33,
 [37.37, 34.26, 33.78, 33.82, 36.33, [...]],
 [34.4, 39.32, 35.61, 38.12, 34.11],
 [33.1, 35.14, 36.76, 33.66, 34.31]]
```

I wasn't expecting `[...]`, so I checked the value of f
and it was

```
[37.37, 34.26, 33.78, 33.82, 36.33, [...]]
```

different from before,

can someone explain to me what is happening here I'm quite new to python.

Comment: Short answer: use `extend` instead of `append`.  You use `append` to add a single element to a list.  If that element is a list, you end up with a nested list, which is what the `[...]` in your output represents.

Comment: You can also use `f *= 2` if you just want to double the list -- that's a little more idiomatic than `f.extend(f)` IMO.

Comment: @Samwise I'm a bit confused, what's the value of [...]

Comment: `[...]` is just a way to shorten the list when printed.

Comment: Those ellipses are used when you have a list that references itself, otherwise the naive representation would be infinitely recursive

Answer (score 2):

You should try `f = [f, f]` instead of `f.append(f)`.

You are trying to append a list at the last position of your list, resulting in your nested list (the `[...]` is the abbreviated version of `f`, used by the `print` function).